# problem while using findstr

Tags: regex, findstr

I am trying to execute the following pattern in findstr. The findstr is complaining that the

> )]%%)

is unexpected at this time.

I passed the following statement

> findstr
>   %EndPageSetup(.+)(%%[((LastPage)|(Page:
>   \d+))]%%) g:\files\WDDEF07.tmp

WDDE07.tmp is a postscript file.

the file i used is https://rapidshare.com/files/2509921619/WDDEF07.tmp

please help me to solve this error.

Comment: What flavour of regex are you using? perl? .net? javascript? Something else?

Comment: @zespri - logeeks is asking about the findstr.exe command that is part of Windows.  It does "regular expressions" - sort of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you are running this from a command line or a batch file, the command shell is interpreting `|` as a pipe, not an alternation like we regexers are used to.  In the command shell, `|` means to take the standard output of the previous command and 'pipe' it into the next command's standard input, like this:

```
C:\>dir |find ".txt"
```

I found no reference to alternations in the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx).  If you can find a way to do what you want without alternations, you might try the `findstr /G:file` option (where file contains the regular expression).  This way, you won't have to fight the command shell's special characters.